# Seq performance hit when specifying a format string

Tags: performance, coreutils, seq

Running seq *(GNU coreutils 8.21)* without specifying a format string runs extremely quickly compared with any possible format I tried:

```
$ time seq 1e8 > /dev/null
seq 1e8 > /dev/null
0.68s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.703 total

$ time seq -f '%1.f' 1e8 > /dev/null                                                                                                                                                                                                          
seq -f '%1.f' 1e8 > /dev/null
53.82s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 53.875 total
```

What is going on here? Is it possible to reproduce the performance when explicitly providing a format string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite the observation, but it actually makes sense. Here is the source code: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/coreutils/src/seq.c

Firstly, notice the `seq_fast` function and the comment before it is called:

```
608  /* If the following hold:
609     - no format string, [FIXME: relax this, eventually]
610     - integer start (or no start)
611     - integer end
612     - increment == 1 or not specified [FIXME: relax this, eventually]
613     then use the much more efficient integer-only code.  */
```

We see that they have a better algorithm when these conditions are met. Indeed, if we instead add an increment we get the same slower behavior because `print_numbers` is used instead of `seq_fast`:

```
time seq  1e9 > /dev/null 
seq 1e9 > /dev/null  4.68s user 0.09s system 99% cpu 4.770 total


time seq  1 7 1e9 > /dev/null
seq 1 7 1e9 > /dev/null  56.78s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 56.801 total
```

As for why formatting takes even longer (1 minute time with 1e8 instead of 1e9), notice that 53/10^8 seconds = 530 nanoseconds. So on average, format code (which has to run on every single number before printing) adds about 530 nanoseconds per printed number. Considering all the branching and complex logic involved in formatting, this makes sense too.